# replace the forward slash with a hyphen in the URL pattern in laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel-8

i wont to replace the forward slash with a hyphen in the URL pattern in laravel routes, but i'm having trouble doing that !

my routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/mobiles/{brand_slug}/{slug}', 'Frontend\DevicesController@device')->name('device')->where(['brand_slug' => '[a-z0-9_-]+', 'slug' => '[a-z0-9_-]+']);
```

my DevicesController.php

```
public function device(Request $request)
    {                         

        $brand_slug = $request->brand_slug;
        $slug = $request->slug;        

        $brand = DB::table('brands')            
            ->where('slug', $brand_slug) 
            ->where('active', 1)             
            ->first();  

        $device = DB::table('devices')
            ->where('status', 'active')   
            ->where('slug', $slug) 
            ->where('brand_id', $brand->id) 
            ->first();          

        if(!$device) abort(404); 


        return view('frontend/'.$this->config->template.'/device-specs', [          
            // page variables
            'device' => $device,        
            'brand' => $brand,  


        ]);
    }
```

my devices.blade.php

```
<div>
  <a title="{{ $device->brand_title.' '.$device->model }}" href="{{ route('device', ['brand_slug' => $device->brand_slug, 'slug' => $device->slug]) }}" class="image"><h3>{{ $device->brand_title.' '.$device->model }}</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

This code works fine, The link is as follows mysiteurl/mobiles/lenovo/tab-m9
but i wont it like this mysiteurl/mobiles/lenovo-tab-m9 ==> best for SEO.

so i change the route to :

```
Route::get('/mobiles/{brand_slug}-{slug}', 'Frontend\DevicesController@device')->name('device')->where(['brand_slug' => '[a-z0-9_-]+', 'slug' => '[a-z0-9_-]+']);
```

the problem is some devices like mysiteurl/mobiles/lenovo-tab work and others like mysiteurl/mobiles/lenovo-tab-m9 not work give me this err :

```
ErrorException
Attempt to read property "id" on null
```

for this line in controller :

```
->where('brand_id', $brand->id)
```

Any help I would be so grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL pattern is ambiguous: both the brand and the device are allowed to contain a hyphen in their slug.

Pattern matching systems will generally be "greedy" by default when faced with that kind of ambiguity, so "lenovo-tab-m9" ends up being interpreted as a brand "lenovo-tab", device "m9", rather than your intention of brand "lenovo", device "tab-m9".

In this case, a non-greedy match won't really help - in practice, it will just mean that the brand slug can never have a hyphen in. So you can either:

- Accept that brand slugs can never have hyphens, and use `where(['brand_slug' => '[a-z0-9_]+', ...`
- Use some other separator that can't appear in slugs. You could probably make `{brand_slug}--{slug}` work.

Comment: `where(['brand_slug' => '[a-z0-9_]+', ...` this one work, thank u 